# Where to Find Web Service of Delpoyed BPM in BPS Server in wso2?

Tags: wso2, esb, bpmn

I'm new to WSO2 products, I know while integrating BPS with ESB, we require the service of deployed Process

so My Question is:- Where to Find Web Service of Deployed BPM.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a BPM does not result in a Webservice, one or more processes will be deployed instead. You can find these under processes in the BPMN explorer https://[wso2server]:[port]/bpmn-explorer  or they can be accessed through the BPMN rest API [REST API Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/BPMN+REST+API).

If you want webservices that implement processes you should probably go with (WS-)BPEL. [BPEL Reference](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/BPEL+References)

If you want to start/control the process from your webpage you can use the rest API. To start a process using the API you would send a POST request to the following URL:

```
https://<Host Name>:<Port>/bpmn/runtime/process-instances
```

This will create a new instance of the process you have specified in the Request body. All you need to put in the body to create the instance is either the processDefinitionId or processDefinitionKey (you can find both in the BPMN-explorer mentioned above). There are other, optional variables as well as the option to create your instance based on a message but this last option is not recommended.

```
{
   "processDefinitionKey":"sampleJavaServiceTask"
}
```

For more info on this, check out the link to the [BPMN REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS350/BPMN+REST+API)

Comment: Then Is it possible to create a BPM as a service? As I want to trigger BPM through a web page.

Comment: I added more details based on your comment